# Pytube v. 12.0.0 works on windows but not on linux

Tags: python

Im trying to run a youtube downloader with flask and pytube. I programmed it on my windows Pc and everything works fine but now when I try to use the site on my ubuntu server it gives me this error: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone

Its the same error like in other Posts but, the solution following to the answers is installing version 11.0.0. But I tryied version 11.0.0 and 12.0.0 and it only works on my Pc(Windows).

Maybe u know the problem.

Answer (score 1):

410 GONE is a response from the remote server.  However the remote server identifies this connection is resulting in the remote server sending a 410 GONE error.  That's nothing on your code or the script or the library, that's how the remote server responds.  There's nothing *we* or anyone else can do to *fix* the 410 response from the remote server.

For the record, HTTP 410 GONE means this:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 410 Gone client error response code indicates that access to the target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent.

(from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410)

You should probably stop hitting the remote server with your requests, because 410 is a permanent error.

---

Alternatively, if you still believe this to be wrong or incorrect or false, you need to provide a copy of your code here for someone to test-run in a Linux environment and see if they get a 410 GONE still.  Unfortunately, as is, there's nothing *anyone* can do about this.